# CSS:Is it legal to place the style=""?

Tags: html, css

```
<div style="margin-bottom:1em;">
    <input type="submit" value="Guest Access" name="guest_login" class="buttonhmpg" style="width:115px;" style="">
</div>
```

We have "Guest Access" button on a page, based on configuration we are displaying the button, i mean in Configuration File if YES, then we will display the buttton, if NO then we will hide the button using CSS style `style=\"visibility:hidden\"`. but if i remove the `style=""` empty style tag, the configuration of displaying and hiding will not work. But if i remove `style=""`, then it will be displayed always.

My Question is Is it legal to place the `style=""`? Is it beacause of this `style=""`, sometimes the Guest Access button
 is displayed and sometimes hidden?

Comment: You shouldn't have two `style` attributes on the same HTML element.

Comment: as what orique said, do it this way: `style="width:115px;height:0px;"` etc, not `style="width:115px;" style="height:0px;"`

Answer (score 1):

No. Only one instance of any given HTML attribute may appear on an element.

Browsers are required to ignore attributes if one of a matching name already exists on an element.

> When the user agent leaves the attribute name state (and before emitting the tag token, if appropriate), the complete attribute's name must be compared to the other attributes on the same token; if there is already an attribute on the token with the exact same name, then this is a parse error and the new attribute must be dropped, along with the value that gets associated with it (if any).

— http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#attribute-name-state

You can use a single style attribute with your rules separated by semi-colons (as in any other rule-set), but should probably look to moving away from style attributes and using classes to allow your element to be matched by the stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't add just a class?

```
.invisible {
    display: none;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Having two style attributes on the same HTML element is invalid. You should add or remove the `visibility:hidden;` part to the one single style attribute.